# Image upload leading to "MediaTypeNotSupportedException" in spring boot application

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf to try and upload an image and picture at the same time but when I try this it leads to a:

"Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported]"

The implementation for Thymeleaf is below:

```
<form id="application" th:action="@{/admin/newapplication}" th:object="${application}" method="post">
    <h1>Add Application</h1>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="applicationName" placeholder="Application Name" required>
        <i class='bx bxs-user'></i>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password to access application" required>
        <i class='bx bxs-lock-alt' ></i>
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="imageFile" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/jpg"/>
    <div class="input">
        <select name="applicationType" id="Application Type">
            <option value="admin">Navigation</option>
            <option value="user">Waste Management</option>
            <option value="user">Energy Consumption</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Register Application</button>
</form>
```

and in the controller it looks like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/newapplication", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String addApplication(@ModelAttribute Application application, @RequestParam(value = "file",required = false) MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    applicationRepository.save(application);
    fileService.uploadImage(file.getOriginalFilename(),file);
    return "addApplication";
}
```

I've tried debugging in Intellij and this method is never reached due to the error occurring in the initial upload on the thymeleaf side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your thymeleaf template.

```
<form id="application" th:action="@{/admin/newapplication}" th:object="${application}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Because this is what your controller expects to receive

```
@PostMapping(value = "/newapplication", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
```

**Otherwise** you can keep the thymeleaf template as is but update your controller to expect the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
@PostMapping(value = "/newapplication", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
```

Comment: HI thanks for the help, that fixed the error I had but now the actual multipart file isn't being sent to the controller, the object is basically null. 

Would you by any chance know how to fix this?